# NullPointException in Fragment with CheckBox

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

In my aplication i have a fragment were i have any checkbox. When i chek start a TextToSpech. I have created a similar version without fragment and it work fine. But when i implemented it in a fragment it doesn't works. Her is my code:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
private TextToSpeech tts;

ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

public OneFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), getModel());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)returnView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(OneFragment.this);

    return returnView;
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
    }
}

private List<Model> getModel() {
    list.add(new Model("Linux", "S"));
    list.add(new Model("Linux", "S"));
    list.add(new Model("Linux", "S"));
    list.add(new Model("Linux", "S"));
    list.add(new Model("Linux", "S"));

    return list;
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.ITALIAN);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {

            startSpeak();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
}

private void startSpeak() {
    tts.speak("Ciao", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
      for (Model i: list ) {
        if (chk.isChecked()) {
            this.startSpeak();
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the partial LogCat result:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
```

How should i do?

Comment: I know what a null point exception is. But i don't understend because i have this problem when i use fragment. I have build a similar app that works. Now i would create the same app whit fragment (For swipe whit ViewPager) but i haved any problems, some i have fixed it other not. So why i have NullPointException when use fragment?

Answer (score 3):

> i have a fragment were i have any checkbox

If `CheckBox` is inside `Fragment` layout in `R.layout.fragment_one` then use `OneFragment.this.getView()` to access `CheckBox` from layout instead of `getActivity()` :

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)OneFragment.this.getView().findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

Or declare `CheckBox chk` as class level variable and initialize it inside onCreateView :

```
...
chk = (CheckBox)returnView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
...
```

Comment: No this is not the problem. I have the problem at the setOnCheckedChangeListener.

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi: what problem with `setOnCheckedChangeListener` ? it is very clear you are using `getActivity()` for accessing CheckBox from `R.layout.fragment_one`

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi: have you tried to change code according to my answer?

Comment: I have the NullPointException at this code:
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(OneFragment.this); 
And not at this code:
chk = (CheckBox)returnView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi: Please show updated code

Comment: Don't have updated the code

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi: then change your code according to my answer. if issue not get resolved then show me updated code

Comment: I have do it, and with your code have the null point exception at the code that you have give me. With my code haven't this problem. My problem is in the setOnCheckedChangeListener. Here have an NullPointException. Look my LogCat please

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi: `checkBox ` CheckBox is not inside `R.layout.fragment_one` layout? in which layout you have ?

Comment: Yes it is. If i don't call the setOnCheckedChangeListener the app work. When i have implemtented this method it does not work

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi: In which layout you have CheckBox with `checkbox` id?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have forget the i have the CheckBox in row.xml that define the item for the listView that is in fragment_one.xml
Sorry

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi: then set `setOnCheckedChangeListener ` for CheckBox in `getView` method of `MyAdapter ` Adapter. let me know if any help required.Thanks

Comment: It works, thanks and sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi: Great if it's working

Answer (score 0):

try this in your onCheckedChanged method.

```
switch (buttonView.getId())
case R.id.checkBox:
/*
Do something
*/
break;
```

Comment: Nope, this don't work. I have a nullPointException at this code:
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(OneFragment.this)

Comment: in your R.layout.fragment_one you set the id checkBox ? to object ? try change the name of id

Comment: I have the CheckBox in row.xml that define the item for the listView that is in fragment_one.xml

Comment: when you declare  View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false); the returnview contains all id's declare in this view, so if you declare the check box in row.xml you dont try this this returnView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox); because checkbox dont exist

Comment: So, what should i do?

Comment: create on use your checkbox in your adapter MyAdapter no in yoour fragment

Comment: I have resolved thanks.